# How to set all ip address in network_security_config.xml file IONIC

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic-framework, fetch

I am implementing ip ping functionality in ionic where we can check if the ip address is reachable from our network. I used javascript fetch function to achieve this.
Now, on web app, the functionality is working fine I am getting correct response if a ip is not pingable ( For cross-verification I am pining ip from command prompt) but for android mobile app, it always says ip is not reachable.

Fetch ip code:

```
 fetch('//'+newIp, {mode: 'no-cors'}).then(r=>{
                hideLoader();
                alert("IP is reachable")
                
                })
                .catch(e=>{
                    hideLoader()
                    console.log(e);
                    alert("IP is not reachable")
                  });
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config>

  <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">*</domain>

                <domain includeSubdomains="true">0.0.0.0</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I checked that in network_security_config.xml if I am giving any ip address in domain tag then mobile app is reading that IP only and giving results.

I want to make generic change in network_security_config.xml to access all local ip address.